# React copy-to-clipboard not trigering

Tags: reactjs

I have the following element:

```
<CopyToClipboard text={color.color}>
    <ColorBox 
       numberOfShades={this.props.numberOfShades} 
       color={color.color} 
       name={color.colorName}
       copy={this.state.copied}
       luminanceLevel={this.state.luminanceSlider} 
       colorFormat={this.state.colorFormat}
    >
        <StyledLink to={{
               pathname: `/shades/${this.props.name}`,
                    state: {
                              color: this.props.color
                            }
         }}>More</StyledLink>
    </ColorBox>
</CopyToClipboard>
```

The `<CopyToClipboard>` is in the React tree with the right text but it doesn't copy when I click in the element.

The child element is:

```
function ColorBox(props){
    return(
            <StyledColorBox color={props.color}>
                {props.copy &&
                    <BoxOverlay
                        colorOverlay={props.color}
                    >
                        <CopiedSign>Copied!</CopiedSign>
                    </BoxOverlay>
                }


                {props.name &&
                    <ColorName>{props.name}</ColorName>
                }
                {props.children}

            </StyledColorBox>
    )
}
```

When I use `<CopyToClipboard>` inside the child element it works. Anyone knows what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If some day anyone have the same issue:

copy-to-clipboard clones the child component and creates an onClick on it, so I just had to call onClick as a prop on the child component.

```
function ColorBox(props){
    return(
            <StyledColorBox color={props.color} onClick={props.onClick}>
                {props.copy &&
                    <BoxOverlay
                        colorOverlay={props.color}
                    >
                        <CopiedSign>Copied!</CopiedSign>
                    </BoxOverlay>
                }


                {props.name &&
                    <ColorName>{props.name}</ColorName>
                }
                {props.children}

            </StyledColorBox>
    )
}
```